# Time reversal by the means of lightspeed

Tags: spaceships, time-travel

In Star Trek, going faster then light will take you back in time (Possibly in real life too!). But I've noticed one inconsistency. Ships, even when going faster then light, have a finite speed. By going faster then light, wouldn't ships, well, collide/intersect with their past versions?

Comment: Star Trek series are all inconsistent between each other in what distances and warp speeds are.  In real life there is no FTL and you cannot travel backwards in time using FTL for that reason alone.

Comment: I suggest https://www.sciencealert.com/faster-than-light-speeds-could-be-the-reason-why-gamma-ray-bursts-seem-to-go-backwards-in-time?utm_source=quora&utm_medium=referral

Answer (score 4):

No.

They are moving in two directions: forwards and in time. So lets just plot their course. At T=10 they reach FTL timetravel speed, for simplicity I'm ignoring time dilation and their acceleration. They start at T=0 and X=0.

T=1 has X=1. T=5 X=5. Then they reach T=10 X=10. After that it gets interesting.

At X=11 they are back at T=9. X=15 T=5 and X=20 they are at T=0, the same time they started accelerating but X=20 further from their startingpoint. They dont collide, but they could give each other a wave as they are taken farther back in time.

A more interesting question: why does everyone assume FTL causes timetravel besides "everyone else says it"? At 0,5C compared to earth you can determine that the 0.5C object has a slower time (or anything slower speeds up). At 0,9C the object has slowed down even more (or the rest sped up). At 1C infinite time passes in anything slower before a single moment passes for the object as the object is infinitely slow. Then when FTL speeds are reached you would expect the object to gain negative time, and for every second that earth gets older the object starts getting younger. But surprise! Suddenly it is the entire universe that gets younger instead! Completely the opposite of the trend we saw approaching the speed of light.

This has bugged me for a while and I cant find any answers to it. Every time its just "as you can see time now flows back for everyone else".

Comment: To solve your last question, I'd link again to https://www.sciencealert.com/faster-than-light-speeds-could-be-the-reason-why-gamma-ray-bursts-seem-to-go-backwards-in-time?utm_source=quora&utm_medium=referral . I understand your solution and I came up with it earlier. But the spaceship has length. If the spaceship's x=1, then when X=10.25 and T = 9.75, they would have intersected with their old spaceship which is at X=9.75 and T = 9.75. Right?

Comment: As far as I read it the link does not contain anything about the particles colliding with themselves but I understand the idea. One of two things would happen: 1. The ship will clip into itself with a planck length (or less!) Of distance between every single particle and cause fusion causing it to explode. 2. Time is also handled as a distance factor. The ship will "hit" the other ship with its inverse time velocity, but the difference is tiny at that point causing little damage (as far as time collisions can be predicted). The ship will not time travel until the earlier ship is out of the way

Comment: I think the ‘FTL makes you go backwards in time’ thing arose as a popular misunderstanding of ‘FTL breaks causality’. Not sure why it sticks around though.

Comment: @JoeBloggs It's not a misunderstanding--you can create scenarios combining FTL and relativistic time dilation to end up in the past **according to some observers**.  Note that a FTL drive that imposes a reference frame (say, requiring you to be at rest relative to some universal measuring scale) does not suffer from this.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Think of the standard twin paradox of relativity--there's no paradox because to actually meet up again one must turn around and come back.  However, if they both make FTL jumps and meet up that way you no longer have the out of one being in an accelerated reference frame and you can't resolve who is older.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Quite right. I was referring to the concept of going so fast that you see time start to flow backwards or just go back in time as a function of going fast. That's not right. It might be if you FTL the right way, but it doesn't happen by default.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that says FTL travel will let you time travel is the theory of relativity. And the theory of relativity states that it depends on *what you're relative to*. Compared to themself, they're going a speed of zero (assuming they're not accelerating). Even according to them, Earth is going back in time. It's turning around that suddenly bumps you back in time.

Comment: FTL motion can lead to the formation of closed time-like curves (CTCs) which exist in all frames of reference, not just whichever ones you choose to consider.